# Grib_api options in f90

Tags: fortran, grib-api

As we know if I want to get the levelType of each message in a grib file.
I could use this below in f90:
grib_get(igrib(i), 'levelType', ltype)

But when fail it will cause a eccodes error and can't gei the value. As the document of grib_api on the site of ECMWF. I found an option 'f' to force the execution not to fail on error and write 'not_found' string to ltype paramters. My quastion is how can i usethis force option in f90?